# Age Calculation with DOB column from Table A and Date column from Table B

Tags: powerbi, dax, calculation, measure, date

I am new to Power BI and would like to know how I can calculate the age of a customer based on the DOB from Table A and Date from Table B. Table B is a Date table which is used to select a date period to run the report. So the report runs on Month Year e.g run the report for August 2020 etc

I have tried to use datediff(dob,max(date)),year but i am getting the wrong results. E.g if a customer has birth date 01/08/1991 and i run the report for July 2020, the age should be 28 and not 29.

TIA

Comment: Add sample data from both table and your expected output.

Comment: Report run for July 2020     
Sample Data    Expected Result 
Name Measure   Name Measure
Customer A 29   Customer A 28
Customer B 29   Customer B 28

Answer (score 0):

Do not connect those table, Date table is a Parameter table.

Create a measure:

```
Average Age = 
    VAR _maxDate = MAX('Table B'[Date])
RETURN
   AVERAGEX(
        'Table A',
        INT ( YEARFRAC ( Customer[Birthdate], _maxDate, 1 ) )
   )
```

[source of the code is from sqlbi.com go check the article for more details](https://www.sqlbi.com/blog/marco/2018/06/24/correct-calculate-of-age-in-dax-from-birthday/)

*Did not tested this out.*

Comment: Hi, I have tried the measure, but it is still showing me age 29 instead of 28 when i select July 2020?

Answer (score 0):

Instead "year" use "hours" and then transform the result to years

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).